# Passing JSON response data from an activity to a fragment in android

Tags: android, json, request, android-volley

I need to pass the username & token that return from json response(logcat successful) from my LoginActivity so that I can set them as parameters for a new http request.

How can I do it?

[image: LoginActivity]

[image: CarListFragment]

By the way, If possible can you also teach me how can I display all the cars using foreach loop or something!

Comment: Use SharedPreferences to store at least the username. Never store passwords in plaintext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your parameter as bundle data to fragment.

```
CarFragment carfragment= new CarFragment();
 Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("username",username);
    bundle.putString("token",token);
   carfragment.setArguments(bundle);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_container,carFragment).commit();
```

you can retrieve this data from carfragment onCreate() method

```
  Bundle bundle= getArguments();
    String username= bundle.getString("username");
    String token = bundle.getString("token");
```

For each can be coded as

```
for(Car car : carList){
// do your stuff using "car" variable
}
```

or

you can use SharedPreference to store username and token

in your login callback result ,save username and token

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("username",username);
    editor.putString("token",token);
    editor.apply();
```

in your carFragment use this code to retrieve data

```
 SharedPreferences preferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username=preferences.getString("username","");
    String token = preferences.getString("token","");
```

Note: Storing sensitive data in preference is risky.. So try to encrypt your token. and decrypt when ever you need..

Comment: Vinayak, Im not sure what container in replace() method, What do I have to put there?

Comment: Put your framelayout id in that place. Its in your xml file

Comment: I understand. I need to try!

Comment: Vinayak. I got this error.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.vnetgps.topgps.BottomNavigationFragments.CarListFragment.onCreateView(CarListFragment.java:47)

Comment: are you calling your fragment from Login activity or main activity?

Comment: I send the username & password from LoginActivity to MainActivity first (Test this ok). Then from MainActivity to CarListFragment, I follow your instructions.

Comment: I am reading this as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Comment: Can you double check the key("username" and  "token") used in main activity and car fragment are same.

Comment: Sure It is the same, Vinayak. I found out that It works/shows only for the first time, if I click the button again. The application crashed and give me that NullPointerException.

Comment: If you want to use your token multiple times the you can save your data in preferences. I edited my ans. please check it

Comment: Okay, I will try and let you know later. Thanks alot!